# Do Older Versions of Windows Have This Registry Key

Tags: windows, windows-xp, registry

Do older versions of Windows OS - meaning Windows Vista and lower - have the following registry entry:

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ProgramFilesDir`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Older versions of Windows do have that key. However, use of that key is an implementation detail. You should use the CSIDL API to locate the program files directory and other special locations.

You are looking for CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES and SHGetSpecialFolderPath.

Answer (score 0):

The `ProgramFilesDir` registry value is located in the following registry subkey:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion

This applies to Vista, XP, 2000.

See more information in [Microsoft support.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/933700)